# Combining Functions Into One Equation

Tags: graphing-functions

I was wondering if anyone could help with this problem I've been having.

I want to do something similar to the famous Batman equation where multiple smaller functions used to make small parts of the Batman logo were combined into one giant equation.

The way this was achieved was by setting all of the smaller functions equal to zero, multiplying them all together, and setting the final equation equal to zero.

[This is the shape I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGZbw.png)

As you can see I have the individual lines figured out, the first one obviously being the circle and the other two the lines. When I multiply them together the huge radical that restricts the range of the lines distributes to the circle and deletes it but I was wondering if there was any way to stop that. Is there any way to combine the three equations into one?

Comment: A short advice (feel free to consider this as coming from a "Dutch uncle") : abandon these kinds of methods that are deadends ;  take advantage of methods that have become universal for drawing (CAD) , i.e., Bezier curves, spline curves, NURBS, and all their avatars.

Comment: This isn't for practical purposes just to see if there was a way to make this into eventually a huge picture with a lot of equations combined.